# sending string parameter in action=track leanplum Rest Api not working

Tags: api, actionscript-3, flash, analytics, leanplum

I want to send string parameters in Leanplum api using action script 
Eg param:{"Element":"Hi"}

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.leanplum.com/api");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var variables:URLVariables = urlVariables;
variables.userId = userId;      
variables.event = eventName;
var params:Object = new Object();
params.Element = "Hi";
var paramStr:String = JSON.stringify(params);
variables.params = paramStr;
variables.appId = appId;
variables.clientKey = clientKeyProduction;
variables.apiVersion = apiVersion;
variables.action = "track";
variables.versionName = AppInfo.getInstance().appVersion;
request.data = variables;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
                trace(e.target.data);
            });

loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
                trace(e.target.data);
            });

loader.load(request);
```

This is actual Request (App ID and ClientKey are dummy):
https://www.leanplum.com/api?clientKey=V42fKaJaBuE&userId=1010&params={"Element":"Ur"}&appId=HEVdDlXiBVLwk&event=Element_Opened&action=track&versionName=2.3.0&apiVersion=1.0.6&info=Lu

Encoded Request:
https://www.leanplum.com%2Fapi%3FclientKey%3DV42fKaJaBuE%26userId%3D1010%26params%3D%7B%22Element%22%3A%22Ur%22
%7D%26appId%3DHEVdDlXiBVLwk%26event%3DElement_Opened%26action%3Dtrack%26versionName%3D2.3.0%26apiVersion%3D1.0.6%26info%3DLu

if I run above request in any rest client I get the same status success : true .

I am getting the response {"response": [{"success": true}]} but I can't find the parameters with value string in Leanplum dashboard, its listing parameter name but not the String Value for parameter.

Comment: Reading the API doc https://www.leanplum.com/docs#/setup/api it seems like you need to pass an `action` to your request.

Comment: @blue112 sorry, I updated the code, but problem is something else, if you don't pass action, you will get error in response. but in my case its success = true

Comment: using `track`, you need to pass an `event`. Could you please show us DEFINITIVE code ?

Comment: Why downvote I just updated the code, Please help.

Comment: Maybe try to URLEncode your json string ? I'm not sure it's gonna fit well as is.

Comment: not It will be automatically urlEncoded If you use it in browser. trying to contact Leanplum support.....

Comment: Finally found the way thanks to leanplum support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply some combination of filters then you can see values of parameter you sent to leanplum. like First select the occurrence of some event then apply Group by parameter then select parameter you want to see the data for.

Its a little different from flurry, Google analytics etc.

[image]